# Where to store application constants in Zend?

Tags: php, zend-framework, constants

I have a few constants that I'll need to define for my application, for example, SITE_KEY which would contain a random key for salt passwords.

I'm not sure where I should define those, though. I thought of placing them in  public/index.php but that seems a bit messy. Is there a specific place where they should go, according to Zend or something?

Thanks

**EDIT**

I'm trying to do it this way:
In my `application.ini` I have this:

`siteglobal.sitekey = "test"`

and in my `bootstrap.php` file:

```
protected function _initGlobals()
{
$config = $this->getOptions();
define('SITE_KEY', $config['siteglobal']['sitekey']);

}
```

Still, this isn't working, when I try to echo SITE_KEY in my controller like this:

`echo SITE_KEY;`

It doesn't show anything. Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In my application, I'm combining both Haim's and Yeroon's approaches. I'm storing application constants in my `application.ini`, then parsing them in the `Bootstrap` and putting them into `Zend_Registry`.

So, in the `application.ini`

```
constants.site_key = my_site_key
```

In the `Bootstrap`

```
protected function _initConstants()
{
    $registry = Zend_Registry::getInstance();
    $registry->constants = new Zend_Config( $this->getApplication()->getOption('constants') );
}
```

Then I can access these constants from any place in the application (model, controller, etc.)

```
Zend_Registry::getInstance()->constants->site_key
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I was trying to acheive the same thing with define, but it didn't work out.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [Zend_Registry](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.registry.html)? It's used to store application-wide values, objects etc.

Store:

```
Zend_Registry::set('index', $value);
```

Retrieve:

```
$value = Zend_Registry::get('index');
```

Comment: No I haven't, thanks for mentioning. In which file would I store them though? That's kind of my question, because I could also simply use define() but I don't really know where to place these constants.

Answer (score 0):

in

> application/configs/application.ini

```
myvar = myvalue
```

after get them like :

```
$myvar = $application->getOption('myvar');
```

[read more ....](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.application.quick-start.html)

Comment: if you in function use global $application;

Comment: in public/index.php you set this parameter, look at the link i wrote

Comment: I cant use $this in index.php because I'm not within an object?

Comment: That seems to work, but how would I call $var from my Controller? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Haim Use `global`?! You can't actually be serious